Derivation of the Fokker-Planck equation
A nonlinear dynamical system is considered
$$ dx/dt = f(x) + z(x)p(t), $$
where $p(t)$ Gaussian noise with zero mean and exponential correlation function.
How I can derivation of the Fokker-Plank formula for the probability density $W(x,t)$ with using smallness of the correlation time?

Hi, welcome to Physics SE. This does what you want with slight notational differences.
